# Where is "Actions groups" in Monitor (Azure)?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-cost-management-budget-scenario#create-the-azure-budget) for billing and budget management.

Now I arrived to:

[image]

But I can't find it on Azure Portal:

[image]

I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the steps as below.

Navigate to `Monitor` -> `Alerts` -> `Manage action groups` -> `Add action group`.

See:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups